# set Dot for CALayer Font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, calayer

I am using core text for `CALayer`.  It is easy to change the color in each layer, but I want this type of Layer:

[image]

How can I set dots under the text in `CALayer`?

Comment: use custom font to add dot in layer, but it not different color,the font and dot with same color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am get solution,my designer create a new custom font to solve this problem,we replace dot into star,but the character and star is not a different color, the both are same color in custom font in my project
[image]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :: I was partly wrong. The CATextLayer CAN draw rich texts in the form of CTAttributedString.. which is  NSAttributedString where all the attributes are identified by their CoreText kCTAttribute constants.

---

WRONG (I mean.. doable but not needed):: I'd use a custom calayer. catextlayer cant draw rich text anyways. in there override dawInContext and draw the attributedstring yourself